# How much escrow/ Multi-signature transactions are done?

Tags: multi-signature, escrow

I have read [here](https://blockchain.info/wallet/escrow) about the possibility of Multi-signature transactions. Is there a statistic available how much of these are done?

Answer (score 3):

Blockchain doesn't currently offer that and the only way to construct a transaction like that is to build it manually.  So as a result both the sender and each recipient must have l33t skills.

This capability will come, it is just that since that was introduced, scalability had to take priority over new features for most Bitcoin development.

They happen but rarely.  Here's an example of Bitcoin address used recently (March 5, 2013) in an escrow transaction:

,- http://blockchain.info/address/13MH4zmU4UT4Ct6BhoRFGjigC8gN9a9FNn

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice statistics http://webbtc.com/stats of different script type

Comment: But not how many multi-signature transaction, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want the number if msig outputs? 87477 right now. Or are you looking for the number of multisignature scriptSigs in the blockchain? In other words: fundings or spendings?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some analysis of the multisig P2SH transactions in the blockchain; http://www.coindesk.com/year-multisig-so-far/ Around April this year there were like 7,000 transactions. I have the frequency per 2500 blocks, showing a nice histogram of their increasing usage, and also the top 4 address types (2-of-3, 2-of-2, etc).